# Java - Adding 'int' into an 'object rows [][]' table

Tags: java, arrays

```
Object rows [][][][]={
                {guessArray[0], guessArray[1], guessArray[2], guessArray[3], }
        };
```

When I tried this, it gives me a type mismatch error (stuff in the array are 'int's), how can I store values from an array into a table?

Comment: Why do you have 4 [] when initializing your array?

Comment: According to the title, I suppose that you have too many dimensions here `[][][][]`. The number of `[]` should not equal to the number of elements.

Comment: You only need two []'s to make an array of arrays (a 2d array). If the stuff inside the guess arrays are integers, than you've just made another array of integers. Also, the brackets should go before the name, and after the data type (ex. `Foo[][] bar;`)